# Inherit from two abstract classes, where one of them also needs parts of the other base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

This is more of a theoretical question without actual code example and I'm not sure if I am just overthinking this.

The whole thing is part of a GUI implemenation I am working on, where the GUI is represented as a tree structure consisting of `Leafs` and `Nodes` specializations which then have some special behavior like text content, an image or whatever which gets handled in its specific `render()` implementation.
However, my problem here is, that i would like to have a `Hover` functionality on some GUIs but that `Hover` functionality needs !some! of the basic GUI element functions, shown in the diagram, and now I can't wrap my head around how i connect these two parts into the final `Button` class. It has to inherit all the `Leaf` functionality plus the abstract `Hover` stuff.

[image: UML Diagram]

Is there a way to make this work the way I am imagining it? Or do i have to give this `Hover` functionality to all GUIs and just implement a blank `onMouseEnter()`and `onMouseExit()` for the ones that don't use it?
The reason I would like to not give it to all GUIs is because the check if the mouse is hovering over the element is not for free. And not all elements have to be interactive.

**A few notes:**
- `Hover` might also be inherited by a Node specialization
- The list of functions in `Hover` is complete
- `Leaf` and `Node` both implement some of the abstract functions from `Element` in different ways

**If you can come up with a better title for this, feel free to suggest an edit**

Comment: Let `Hover` inherit from `Element`. Then `Leaf` and `Node` inherits from `Element` or `Hover` depending on what it needs. The ones inheriting from `Hover` will still be `Element`s.

Comment: Then i would have to have two seperate `Hover` classes, one for `Leaf` and one for `Node` though because `Leaf` and `Node` both implement some of the abstract `Element` functions. I will add this to my question in the notes

Comment: Uhm... no you won't? Leaf and Node would still be able to implement all, none or any of the abstract element functions.

Comment: @super Yes, sorry i misread what you wrote there. However wouldn't i then need a `Leaf` and `Leaf_Hover` (same for `Node`) to inherit from for other special elements? Like a `Label` for example, is a `Leaf` and doesn't want the `Hover` functionality. Or is there a way to inherit from multiple bases and chose the correct one depending on the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extract the common functionalities of Element and Hover into a common base class:

```
           MouseBase
               |
 ------------------------------
 |                            |
 |                          Element
 |                            |
Hover                         |
 |             -------------------------------
 |             |                             |
 |            Leaf                          Node
 ---------------
        |
      Button
```

In that case, if MouseBase is a virtual base class, Button will get one single version of it, else it will have one via Element inheritance and a second one via Hover inheritance.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, I will try that out.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how to solve the problem of a function being ambiguous when inheriting from `Hover` and `Leaf`? `onMouseMovedEvent` has to be in `MouseBase` and is overridden in `Hover` and in `Leaf`

Comment: @DJSchaffner: you will have to disambiguate by saying which one you want, for example `Hover::onMouseEvent`. `using` is generally used to have nicer names.

Comment: With your suggestions i got it to work. Thanks! I had to let `Element` and `Hover` inherit `public virtual MouseBase` and moved some basic functionality into that class.